# Writing content from fetch in variable fails

Tags: javascript, plugins, fetch

I have a problem where I have been sitting for hours now. I did a lot of research, but of the many attempts, nothing worked.

The problem occurs when programming a browser plugin. With the help of fetch, I would like to read out a JSON file from the web_accessible_resources and save it in a global variable, so that I have much easier access afterwards.

But no matter what I try, it does not succeed. Below are the important parts of the code.

Main function calls:

```
createGlobalWebsiteInformation();
console.log(globalWebsiteInformation.twitter);
```

The fetch function:

```
function createGlobalWebsiteInformation()
{
    // Daten aus websites.json
    var websitesURL = browser.runtime.getURL("json/websites.json"); // URL der websites.json
    var obj;

    fetch(websitesURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => obj = data)
      .then(() => writeToGlobal(obj));
}
```

The function to write in the global variable

```
function writeToGlobal(obj)
{
    for (const ws of obj.websites)
    {
        globalWebsiteInformation[ws.website] = ws;
    }
}
```

So the console.log is always "undefined" and not the website information for twitter that are stored in the JSON...

Comment: did you try console.log(res) ? Is there anything there?

Comment: Yes, up to this point and also in the function writeToGlobal() I can access the JSON content. Only the access after it has been written to the global variable does not work. I guess it's a timing issue and I can not fix it because fetch() and .then() are still very new to me.

Comment: did you try attaching to window directly? Like window.globalWebsiteInformation[ws.website] = ws;